# h2o.deeplearning not using negative offset

Tags: r, h2o

I am using h2o.deeplearning to build poisson models, so I am offsetting the exposure weights (I also need to use other offset values in the future). Because they are the log of numbers smaller than 1, all offset values are negative.

I noticed when scoring, negative offsets are not used.

I am using the latest h2o version on CRAN, 3.22.1.1.

R version 3.6.0.

Reproducible example:

```r
# Setup
set.seed(1234)
install.packages("h2o")
install.packages("insuranceData")
library(h2o)
library(insuranceData)
h2o.init()
h2o.getVersion()  # "3.22.1.1

data(dataCar)
dataCar$log_exposure <- log(dataCar$exposure)
# log_exposure contains negative values
summary(dataCar$log_exposure)

# Build model
dataCar.h2o <- as.h2o(dataCar)
dl <- h2o.deeplearning(x = c("veh_value", "veh_body", "veh_age", "gender", "area", "agecat"),
                       y = "numclaims",
                       training_frame = dataCar.h2o,
                       nfolds = 5,
                       offset_column = "log_exposure",
                       distribution = "poisson",
                       reproducible = TRUE)

# Prediction Scenarios
dataCar_offsetadj <- dataCar[1,]

# Offset 0
dataCar_offsetadj$log_exposure <- 0
pred1 <- h2o.predict(dl, as.h2o(dataCar_offsetadj))
print(pred1)
# 0.1058487

# Offset 1.5
dataCar_offsetadj$log_exposure <- 1.5
pred2 <- h2o.predict(dl, as.h2o(dataCar_offsetadj))
print(pred2)
# 0.4743808  # Different value, as expected

# Offset -1.5
dataCar_offsetadj$log_exposure <- -1.5
pred3 <- h2o.predict(dl, as.h2o(dataCar_offsetadj))
print(pred3)
# 0.1058487  # Same value as offset 0

# Offset -2
dataCar_offsetadj$log_exposure <- -2
pred4 <- h2o.predict(dl, as.h2o(dataCar_offsetadj))
print(pred4)
# 0.1058487  # again, same value

all.equal(pred1, pred3)  # TRUE
all.equal(pred1, pred4)  # TRUE
```

I would expect the predictions with the negative offsets to all be different. The positive offset has a different score as expected.

It seems like h2o is not applying negative offsets. Is this correct? What would be the reason for doing this? Does this also mean the negative offsets are not used when creating the model? How would I get around this problem? I will need to build more deep learning models with different distributions and negative offsets in the future.

Appreciate any advice, thanks.

Comment: hi @stephanieR are you updating your model with a new offset value each time or simply appending a new column when you do your predictions? thanks!

Comment: Hi @Lauren, I will have a final column of offsets when i build my models (which contain negative values). I changed the offset values above to show that the negative offsets make no difference to the predicted value.